# Find slope from correlation coefficient of pearson method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, statistics

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", 
              sep='\t', 
              names= ["ElementID","Load"])

df.insert(0, 'count', df.groupby('ElementID').cumcount())


df2 = df.pivot(index='count',columns='ElementID', values='Load')
df2_norm = df2.apply(lambda x: (x / x.abs().max())) 
allowableCorr = df2_norm.corr(method = 'pearson') 
    
slope = allowableCorr * (df2_norm.std().values / 
df2_norm.std().values[:, np.newaxis])
```

I have a lot of datasets which I use the .corr method to get the r^2 value. However , the code above does not always match the slope results. I am using excel to test the slope value. What am i doing wrong?

test.txt

716865    -301.70224
716865   -1258.647095
716865     126.767021
716865     701.922852
716865     742.309021
716865    -150.711334
716865     392.487152
716865     -91.858528
716865      33.217159
716865     883.334717
716865     143.003952
716865    -127.804535
716865     340.573639
716865    -911.843262
716865     210.663971
716865    -337.319061
716865    -574.554688
716865     -85.879967
716865      55.362972
716865    -598.517029
716865    -507.735901
716865    -806.568481
716865     -768.94989
716865      815.82489
716865    -780.519714
716865    1077.297729
716865   -1882.155151
716865     -21.309252
716865     -14.403346
716865     100.049232
716865     125.137939
716865      94.089989
716865     -36.337738
716865     104.333527
716865    -433.559021
716865       4.860066
716865    -190.261063
716865    -216.324509
716865     -13.302347
716865       15.41076
716865      -23.88785
716865       4.825286
716865       6.271163
716865        9.85747
716865     -11.765738
716865      -8.179381
716865      11.288673
716865       7.702322
716865     -10.334545
716865      -6.748201
716865     -32.338951
716865       0.034022
716865      -7.783642
716865       1.344555
716865       1.008542
716865        7.51763
716865       4.278917
716865      13.613921
716865       0.657209
716865       0.004726
716865      -0.008553
716865       0.321643
716865     -28.621054
716865     -25.886494
716865       1.211354
716865      -7.711781
716865     -17.332674
716865       1.641209
716865       0.726812
716865       0.740472
716865     -17.371124
716865       1.453994
716865       7.715975
716865      -0.276754
716865     -31.113707
716865     -17.472322
716865       0.543816
716865      -5.014119
716865     -18.576653
716865       1.347938
716865       0.565348
716865       0.883058
716865     -18.696476
716865       1.037493
716865       5.044785
716865       0.102762
716865     -30.731455
716865      -21.54364
716865       0.843278
716865      -6.287022
716865     -18.482023
716865       1.480709
716865       0.587757
716865       0.770442
716865     -18.555861
716865       1.274093
716865       6.298359
716865      -0.032861
716865     -16.837095
716865     -39.867527
716865       3.341571
716865     -12.108704
716865     -13.806955
716865       2.490994
716865       1.773459
716865       0.826912
716865     -13.895108
716865       1.067095
716865      12.295836
716865       0.017253
716865      -0.017011
716865       -0.03412
716865       0.012205
716865       0.011363
716865      -0.011869
716865       0.025908
716865       0.005893
716865      -0.001441
716865       0.023322
716865      -0.011226
716865      -0.019583
716865          0.006
716865       -0.00641
716865     324.205536
716865     133.731796
716865    -203.469788
716865     422.581543
716865     150.133972
716865    -371.098114
716865     282.197632
716865      79.024696
716865    -181.467117
716865     279.187439
716865     150.074112
716865      99.900131
716865     263.611481
716865      59.430237
716865     -177.68248
716865      88.130081
716865      19.783554
716865     156.729797
716865     159.243668
716865     -96.671829
716865      99.567726
716865     153.336472
716865     -65.270882
716865      -8.313629
716865      -1.822799
716865      14.163381
716865      -0.027411
716865      -7.346685
716865       2.321136
716865       0.553517
716865       7.307581
716865       7.573683
716865        3.40268
716865       0.237121
716865       0.243131
716873    -116.165497
716873    -934.009277
716873     121.008446
716873     674.810791
716873     699.712646
716873     -32.448597
716873     404.385559
716873      44.291641
716873     154.319611
716873    1004.978394
716873     109.746536
716873       9.751794
716873     291.211395
716873    -873.794312
716873     197.930389
716873    -371.370331
716873    -506.104797
716873     -62.006485
716873      42.805466
716873    -530.312378
716873    -530.244873
716873    -762.327087
716873    -760.558655
716873     753.133484
716873    -768.190125
716873     993.777344
716873   -1522.421875
716873     -45.851994
716873     -16.078772
716873     102.985107
716873     112.955887
716873      84.928909
716873     -31.930878
716873      79.560143
716873    -386.377625
716873        1.69816
716873     -171.38002
716873    -186.184341
716873      -9.310679
716873       11.53948
716873     -28.820801
716873      -7.970621
716873      -3.674594
716873      14.181245
716873     -17.635487
716873       0.220536
716873       16.77195
716873      -1.084055
716873     -15.044891
716873       2.811084
716873     -22.310444
716873       0.070187
716873      -6.526618
716873       0.519358
716873        0.93114
716873       6.270535
716873       3.045897
716873       14.72409
716873       0.496607
716873       0.003259
716873      -0.008807
716873      -0.961357
716873     -22.897137
716873     -15.484076
716873       1.015296
716873      -2.042436
716873      -13.44498
716873       1.506008
716873       1.075834
716873       1.359961
716873      -13.63349
716873       1.321194
716873       2.128678
716873      -1.336552
716873      -25.49177
716873      -8.724606
716873       0.443453
716873       0.254901
716873     -14.597396
716873       1.296078
716873       0.919975
716873       1.449683
716873     -14.847031
716873       1.014634
716873      -0.157101
716873       -1.07669
716873     -24.886087
716873      -11.84578
716873       0.696825
716873      -0.714679
716873     -14.426558
716873       1.391136
716873       0.949331
716873        1.36829
716873     -14.641159
716873       1.194632
716873       0.800537
716873       -1.58931
716873       -11.3484
716873     -26.018322
716873       2.909623
716873      -5.166547
716873      -9.892995
716873       2.156415
716873        2.01736
716873       1.533689
716873     -10.137015
716873       0.863195
716873       5.458185
716873       0.013926
716873      -0.011724
716873      -0.030154
716873       0.009871
716873       0.007602
716873       -0.00715
716873       0.019485
716873       0.002956
716873       0.006034
716873       0.016784
716873      -0.010138
716873      -0.015378
716873       0.013079
716873       0.044271
716873     299.691345
716873      168.10495
716873    -137.186401
716873     398.893036
716873     178.197784
716873    -308.874573
716873     259.335876
716873     114.582466
716873    -116.212494
716873     272.913727
716873     195.083252
716873     170.973419
716873     242.900848
716873      92.730392
716873    -115.781334
716873      68.182755
716873      64.158295
716873     206.475113
716873     138.817078
716873     -59.660057
716873     170.986923
716873     140.095535
716873     -17.554855
716873      66.050301
716873      -2.712554
716873      27.134666
716873       0.025514
716873      -6.399142
716873       1.683879
716873       0.518694
716873       6.318477
716873       6.471766
716873       2.251963
716873       0.245339
716873       0.184508
716884     124.174957
716884     -543.34314
716884     102.258514
716884     622.506165
716884     618.796204
716884     132.756882
716884     405.259003
716884     206.318359
716884     301.309723
716884    1106.663208
716884      67.389801
716884     180.681015
716884     221.693985
716884    -792.332825
716884     175.221024
716884     -375.52652
716884    -444.379303
716884     -19.328663
716884      26.917398
716884     -468.37439
716884     -515.50531
716884    -679.881104
716884     -713.56427
716884     652.319946
716884    -716.638184
716884     869.534119
716884   -1034.596313
716884     -84.932793
716884     -29.275459
716884     116.723412
716884      95.447914
716884      71.762871
716884     -25.168804
716884      51.524746
716884    -322.065582
716884      -2.099667
716884    -145.098633
716884      -145.8358
716884      -2.416266
716884       5.303814
716884     -30.934532
716884     -23.214443
716884     -15.070092
716884      16.879007
716884     -22.298216
716884       9.651199
716884       20.94346
716884     -11.005925
716884     -18.233974
716884      13.715357
716884      -8.202349
716884       0.089903
716884      -4.866776
716884      -0.381067
716884       0.791291
716884         4.6311
716884       1.777163
716884      14.526459
716884        0.23941
716884       0.000919
716884      -0.009061
716884      -2.354227
716884     -13.142694
716884      -5.054462
716884       1.041731
716884       3.568333
716884      -7.150105
716884        1.36466
716884       1.518771
716884       2.044704
716884      -7.480896
716884       1.212836
716884      -3.389907
716884      -2.454151
716884      -15.93776
716884      -0.349828
716884       0.577748
716884       5.338133
716884      -8.199544
716884       1.254575
716884       1.369443
716884       2.070532
716884      -8.562329
716884       1.042838
716884      -5.167105
716884      -2.343827
716884     -14.996009
716884      -2.326019
716884       0.778757
716884       4.732598
716884      -7.909725
716884       1.304329
716884       1.408948
716884        2.02876
716884      -8.252971
716884       1.153241
716884      -4.564247
716884       -3.33852
716884       -1.51058
716884     -11.481308
716884        2.67605
716884       1.928831
716884      -3.384082
716884       1.771827
716884        2.34195
716884       2.333492
716884      -3.787011
716884       0.652604
716884      -1.514875
716884       0.009002
716884      -0.003013
716884      -0.027728
716884       0.006013
716884       0.000874
716884        0.00072
716884       0.009466
716884      -0.002151
716884       0.020411
716884       0.007046
716884      -0.006607
716884      -0.017869
716884       0.019977
716884       0.093917
716884     266.815857
716884     218.236526
716884     -23.038584
716884     362.145142
716884     227.943802
716884    -174.718979
716884     228.348831
716884     164.749985
716884      -7.250031
716884     254.411575
716884     256.743378
716884     276.647736
716884     212.703583
716884     138.865784
716884     -13.510377
716884      39.944756
716884     133.330185
716884     291.995575
716884     111.045929
716884      -0.637947
716884     282.187897
716884     116.875557
716884      56.029514
716884     180.233658
716884      -3.815804
716884      39.750874
716884       0.065434
716884      -5.083665
716884       0.926333
716884        0.42528
716884       4.953602
716884       5.192181
716884       1.061818
716884       0.225265
716884        0.09564

Comment: Please share your data to let others reproduce you problem

Comment: I added the data and more code @tstanisl

Comment: @tstanisl I uploaded the data