# Calculate linear regression slope matrix (Same to correlation matrix) - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, statistics

[image]How do I calculate slope of each columns below? The .corr method scans all columns and find the correlation coeffficient with each column. I want to do the same but get slope of the datasets with each other. The slope line of code below does not return expected values. I think I am not using newaxis correctly. I need a 5x5 symmetric matrix with 1 as diagonal which means slope is for y = x. I did it on excel picture attached with the reference being 717024 column. I need to iterate each column and make it as reference.

```
allowableCorr = df2_norm.corr(method = 'pearson') 

slope = allowableCorr * (df2_norm.std().values /  df2_norm.std().values[:, np.newaxis])
```

df2_norm is:

```
 count          716865                 716873                  716884                 716943                 716944

  0   -0.16029615828413712    -0.07630309240006158    0.11220663712532133    -0.2726775504078691    -0.23279127015045065  
  1    -0.6687265363491811     -0.6135022705188075   -0.49097425130988914     -0.736020384028633      -0.705286321388766  
  2    0.06735205699309535     0.07948417451634422    0.09240256047258057     0.0617964313591086     0.06344003100365293  
  3      0.372935701728449     0.44324822316416074     0.5625073287879649     0.3199599294007491      0.3420770859108217  
  4    0.39439310866886124     0.45960496068147993     0.5591549439131621    0.34928093849248304     0.36951024291102974  
  5   -0.08007381002566456   -0.021313801077641505    0.11996141286735541   -0.15572679401876433    -0.12936514230689095  
  6    0.20853071107951396     0.26561990841073535     0.3661990387594055    0.15720649076873264       0.177890807311781  
  7    -0.0488049712326824     0.02909288268076153    0.18643283476719688    -0.1438092892727158    -0.10871022227142838  
  8   0.017648470149950992     0.10136455179350337     0.2722686729095633   -0.07928001803992157   -0.043102822045971705
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7iAd.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including some data in a more convenient format. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62643979/find-slope-from-correlation-coefficient-of-pearson-method is the whole code. I reduced it here for simplicity and for folks not to get overwhelmed. it is something fairly simple.. i am just having a hard time grasping it

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
slope =  np.dot(np.dot(np.diagflat(df2_norm.std().values) , allowableCorr.values), np.diagflat(1/df2_norm.std().values))
```

Comment: no. each column is a dataset. need the slope of column (1,1) aka one with one, (1,2) aka one with two etc..

Comment: @vinnimoh yes,  see the fix.

Comment: it does not seem to be working i get valueerror. diag requires an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: ValueError: diag requires an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: @vinnymoh See now.

Comment: thank you @Igor Ravin. This is the same result I was gettiing. I cannot seem to grasp the concept why the matrix is not symmetrical. I get for the most part a similar slope to excel but a lot of the values dont match. When you correlate y on x and x on y you get the same correlation. why is the slope different then? thank you for any further insight. ill vote your answer up

Comment: @vinnymoh You are looking for regression slopes, right? If `x ~ 2 y`, then 'y ~ 0.5 x` - so the 1, 2 and 2, 1 elements will be multiplicative inverses of each other, so the matrix is not symmetric, no?

Comment: Keep in mind that Code only answers without context or explanation as to how/why your solution addresses the OP's issue are frowned upon.  Long term value and opportunities for learning are absent in code-only answers. Hence future visitors are unlikely to glean much insight to apply to their own code issues. It also minimizes confusion and errors. Consider editing to include more info, caveats, context, and/or explanations to your answers to keep the quality of SO Answers high, and increase your chances of getting upvotes. Thanks for your contribution!